# Decoding JWT string from Google fails [php]

Tags: php, json, google-oauth, decode, jwt

I am trying to decode a JWT encrypted strying in PHP. The string is valid, as it decodes perfectly here: [**Working Demo**](https://py-jwt-decoder.appspot.com/)

I am using this [**GITHUB**](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to decode.

My snippet is, which fetches a public key from google in an array, which works good. But the decoding part gives the following errors.

```
include('JWT.php');

$refresh = false;
if (file_exists('oauthkey')) {
   $age = time() - filemtime('oauthkey');
   if ($age > 20000)
      $refresh = true;   
} else
   $refresh = true;

if ($refresh) {
   $oauthKey = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs')
      or die('Failed to retrieve google public key.');
   $keyFile = fopen('oauthkey', 'w') or die ('Failed to open public key file for writing.');
   fwrite($keyFile, $oauthKey);
   fclose($keyFile);
} else {
   $keyFile = fopen('oauthkey', 'r') or die ('Failed to open public key file for reading.');
   $oauthKey = fread($keyFile, 5000) or die ('Failed to read from public key file.');
   fclose($keyFile);   
}
$oauthKey = json_decode($oauthKey, true); // get key from Google in Array

$jwtstring = 'eyJhbGciOiJS...'; // full long JWT encoded string

$bla = JWT::decode($jwtstring, $oauthKey);

echo print_r($bla);
```

### ERRORS:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 433d0da18366fcdc43301fd1e142294a6209e451 in /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php on line 64
PHP Warning:  openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key in /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php on line 179
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'OpenSSL unable to verify data: ' in /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php(71): JWT::verify('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', '+??????0?????SK...', NULL, 'RS256')
#1 /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/testjwt.php(31): JWT::decode('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/domain.com/php-jwt-master/Authentication/JWT.php on line 181
```

Comment: you could probably pick the code directly out of the Google PHP client lib. my question is why aren't you using the Google php client lib to begin with?  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: As far as I know it's not part for that library. Also Google specifies in their documentation regarding JWT to use https://github.com/luciferous/jwt or https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt for this. Which I have. It's just giving me some errors.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue.

Had to add 'false' to the decode statement.

```
$bla = JWT::decode($jwtstring, $oauthKey, false);
```