# Understanding Sign In with Google

Tags: php, google-signin

I'm trying to implement [Google Sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview?hl=en).

My index.php file is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>         
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<script src="files/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    console.log(response.credential);//ok, long string displayed in the console

    $.ajax({
        url: "signin.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            idtoken: response.credential
        },
        success: function(reply_data) {
            $("#MainContainer").html(reply_data.Comentario);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#MainContainer").html('danger...');
        }
    });             
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="my_id_client_number.apps.googleusercontent.com"//here the proper Client ID
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>

    <div id="MainContainer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen, I send the credential to a signin.php file, where I want to know who is trying to access my site, in order to check if it is allowed (check against a database).

But for this, I need to decode the credential **(and this is my problem)**.

The signin.php file is like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$credencial = $_POST['idtoken'];
$key = base64_encode("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");//(The Client secret from Google console)
$decoded = JWT::decode($credencial, $key, array('HS256'));
$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;

$Comentario=print_r($decoded, true);


$data = array(
    'Comentario' => $Comentario
);
echo json_encode($data);//Send response
?>
```

If I undestand correctly, when user try to login, google retuns a credential that includes a key. So you need to know the key to decode the credential.

**Which is that key?**

I tried with the Client secret from Google console (signin.php file, above).

I also tried getting a public key according to following code (founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494797/decoding-jwt-string-from-google-fails-php)):

```
$refresh = false;
if (file_exists('oauthkey')) {
   $age = time() - filemtime('oauthkey');
   if ($age > 20000)
      $refresh = true;   
} else
   $refresh = true;

if ($refresh) {
   $oauthKey = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs')
      or die('Failed to retrieve google public key.');
   $keyFile = fopen('oauthkey', 'w') or die ('Failed to open public key file for writing.');
   fwrite($keyFile, $oauthKey);
   fclose($keyFile);
} else {
   $keyFile = fopen('oauthkey', 'r') or die ('Failed to open public key file for reading.');
   $oauthKey = fread($keyFile, 5000) or die ('Failed to read from public key file.');
   fclose($keyFile);   
}
$oauthKey = json_decode($oauthKey, true); // get key from Google in Array


$decoded = JWT::decode($credencial, $oauthKey, array('HS256'));
```

But can't get the credential decoded.

**So my two questions are:**

1. Is the logic right? I mean: google send the credential with user data, that credential was built using a key, and you must know the key to decode it.
2. Which key to use?

Comment: Have you tried using any of the existing libraries, to avoid writing all this decoding stuff by hand?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm using [this](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt). Run `composer require firebase/php-jwt`  and `composer require paragonie/sodium_compat` es explained there. I think libraries are in the vendor folder, which are included at the start of the signin.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your logic is a bit off, see the answer for 2) as to why.
2. A secret key is not required to decode the ID token, only your Client ID is. Your Client ID is a not secret, it is after all embedded in your HTML or JS.

The ID token is a JWT that is signed by Google and base64 encoded for safe transport on the across the web. It is not encrypted, so no secret key is required to decode. JWT signing enables you to verify that the ID token came from Google by verifying the signature against the published signing keys (certs).

Google offers a [PHP library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) which I'd highly encourage you to check out and use to help decode and verify the ID token.  You'll end up with a little snippet like this with the PHP library:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me, the problem with this approach is insecure cookie validation:

```
public function googleAuth(): bool
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['credential']) ) {
        if ($_REQUEST['g_csrf_token'] == $_COOKIE['g_csrf_token']) {//both are empty, not used butoom version
            $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => "141066617768-46nqtg4c7md59qdp3p3gmfpvr886b5hn.apps.googleusercontent.com"]);  //use Google\Client as Google_Client; Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
            $userGoogle = $client->verifyIdToken($_REQUEST['credential']);
            if (isset($userGoogle['email'])) {
                return $this->newAccountByEmailGoogle($userGoogle);

            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```